# How to use ProjectExpression with column names with spaces?

Tags: python, string, parsing, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I did a big no no and created a large table which included spaces in the names of the columns. I am trying to scan over this table and select particular pieces of information.

```
    import boto3
    from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
                              region_name='xx-xxxx-xx')
    table = dynamodb.Table('ourtable')

    scan_kwargs = {
        'FilterExpression': Key('primarykey').between(*key_range)
        'ProjectionExpression': "primarykey, other column"
    }

    done = False
    start_key = None
    while not done:
        if start_key:
            scan_kwargs['ExclusiveStartKey'] = start_key
        response = table.scan(**scan_kwargs)
        start_key = response.get('LastEvaluatedKey', None)
        done = start_key is None
```

Running this gives me this error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: Invalid ProjectionExpression: Syntax error; token: "column", near: "other column"
```

I am assuming this is some parsing issues. I have tried a couple of ways of escaping the space to no avail. Those attempts include:

```
{other column}
\'other column\'
\"other column\"
other%20column
other\column
other{BEASPACE}column
```

I would prefer to not remake this table. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: did you try the backtick ` (above the tilde) ? I can't recall at the moment but I think thats how it works... however isnt  `ProjectionExpression` expecting a list of column names?

Comment: you can try this method: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html  also, these expressions/filters work AFTER the scan is returned, so you might find it easier to just the result and use python to do the filtering

Comment: @lynkfox unfortunately, the backtick does not work.

Comment: @JonathanLeon I was thinking about that approach as well. I decided to bite the bullet and spend the weekend recreating the table with the correct column names without spaces. Definitely learned my lesson and will never use spaces in any possible variable ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DynamoDB expressions, instead of "escaping" column names with quotes or backslashes like you tried, what you need to do is to use **references** to names listed in an additional `ExpressionAttributeNames` parameter. For example,

```
scan_kwargs = {
    'FilterExpression': Key('primarykey').between(*key_range)
    'ProjectionExpression': "primarykey, #othercolumn"
    'ExpressionAttributeNames': {'#othercolumn': 'other column'}
}
```

Note how in the projection expression I used the **reference** `#othercolumn` instead of the column's real name, and then defined that real name (which may contain spaces or other special characters) in the `ExpressionAttributeNames`.

This feature is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html